# Keep Redux State in Different Routes

Tags: react-redux, react-router-dom

my home page has AddItem and ShoppingList components. The ShoppingList component displays list of items when I click AddItem. Now I want to click a "View cart" link to open the ShoppingList on a different route but this causes the state gets lost and the ShoppingList is blank. How to keep the Redux store state on a page in different routes?  The sandbox link is here [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shop-drop-redux-forked-nw7vm?file=/src/components/Home.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Redux state will remain as long as you are in the same session.  You need to do all of your navigation through `Link` components from `react-router-dom` rather than `a` tags.  You are using `Link`, but you are losing the state because of `target="_blank"` which opens a new window with a new state.  If you remove `target="_blank"` then it will work just fine.